# C++20 ranges - how to modify a range?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I have a vector defined as:

`auto xs = std::vector<double>(5) = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 };`

and I've created a view on this vector:

`auto vi = xs | std::ranges::views::drop(1);`

for example. However, I'd like to convert the view data into an actionable range or another vector so that I can modify it.

So far, I've tried this:

```
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>

auto tmp = std::vector<double>();
std::ranges::copy_n(std::ranges::rbegin(vi), std::ranges::size(vi) - 1, std::back_inserter(tmp));
std::ranges::action::push_back(tmp, 99.99);
```

but the push_back action isn't recognised. Am I missing a header, if so, which one or isn't this implemented in C++20?

I've also tried:

```
tmp.push_back(99.99);
```

but this doesn't work either.

I'd like to stick to the C++20 implementation rather than use the `ranges` library and the type of `tmp` can be something completely different, such as another type or action/range.

What's the best/most efficient way of doing this, please?

Comment: `ranges` library doesn't have `action`, that's the [`range-v3`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) by ericniebler.

Comment: Also `tmp.push_back(99.99);` seems to work fine for me: https://godbolt.org/z/v4Ycx6TxP

Comment: Also, if you want to create a `vector` from a range view, you can simply do `auto vec = std::vector(std::ranges::rbegin(vi), std::ranges::rend(vi));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I'd like to convert the view data into ... another vector so that I can modify it.

You can use the constructor of std::vector that accepts a pair of iterators:

```
template< class InputIt >
constexpr vector( InputIt first, InputIt last,
                  const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

---

> ```
> std::ranges::action::push_back(tmp, 99.99);
> ```
>
> but the push_back action isn't recognised. Am I missing a header, if so, which one or isn't this implemented in C++20?

The standard library doesn't have `ranges::action`s. You can use member functions instead:

```
tmp.push_back(99.99);
```

> I've also tried:
>
> ```
> tmp.push_back(99.99);
> ```
>
> but this doesn't work either.

I see no reason why that wouldn't work. I recommend thinking about what you were expecting it to do and why you expect that.

Comment: I've figured out why the ```tmp.push_back(99.99)``` didn't work for me! In reality, I'm using a complex type for ```tmp``` and was trying to push a double to that so there was a type conflict!! However, thanks for suggesting the vector constructor method as I wasn't aware of that and it seems the simplest method.